# Subclassed UIButton with properties isn't changing UI

Tags: swift, uibutton, attributes, subclass, init

I have a very simple UIButton subclass with 1 attribute: `bgPropertyColor`. There are 3 buttons in storyboard that all have outlets to this subclass.

I would like to be able to adjust the `bgPropertyColor` attribute from the View Controller. In my example below, I have access to the bgPropertyColor attribute, but the colors (red / blue / green) are not applying to the buttons background as I intend them to.

**UIButton**

```
class CustomButton:UIButton {

    var bgPropertyColor = UIColor.clear

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = bgPropertyColor
    }

}
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var b1: CustomButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var b2: CustomButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var b3: CustomButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        b1.bgPropertyColor = .red
        b2.bgPropertyColor = .blue
        b3.bgPropertyColor = .green
    }

}
```

**How can I initialize the subclassed buttons so that I'm able to fine-tune properties (background color) on each, right on the View Controller?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need

```
var bgPropertyColor : UIColor = UIColor.clear {
  didSet {
    self.backgroundColor  = bgPropertyColor 
  }
}
```

as changing `bgPropertyColor` won't reflect to `backgroundColor` as you might expect , also may be the property is useless as you can change `backgroundColor` it directly in IB/Code

Comment: The property observer did the trick! Thank you. Regarding the useless property - for this example I just used something simple to get the concept working. Ultimately, a few more properties will be set and adjusted within the VC's.